# How to create such a material in Blender?

Tags: materials, node-editor

Can you tell me how to create such a material in Blender? Maybe someone has seen similar tutorial videos. Or can anyone suggest in what direction to move in the nodes?
Material a la curved distorted mirrors, which are distorted in a certain direction (to the center).[image]

Comment: I think there is a distortion node in the compositor

Answer (score 2):

You could create a plane, subdivide it, give it a glass material (Principled BSDF *Transmission* at 1), put it in front of your image:

[image]

In *Sculpt* mode, use the *Draw* brush to deform the plane (invert its effect by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>):

[image]

You could subdivide the image itself and use the *Pinch* brush:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I'll take note. However, I may have left out some details. I'm using an HDRI map that is supposed to reflect off the mirrored plates of the pavilion (the structure in the photo). I would like to adjust the mirror material so that the reflection goes distorted. Maybe it's not the material that needs to be adjusted, but the object itself. 

But I think I'm beginning to realize that such an effect can be achieved only in rendering post-processing.

Comment: @DanilDo I can't tell from [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html) but you might be able to just change the normals, without changing the geometry.